# Get json element from JSON Array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have the sample data for demostration as shown below:

Table:

```
create table tbl_jdata
(
id int,
jdata json
);

insert into tbl_jdata values(1,'[{"salary":10000,"name":"mak"},{"salary":20000,"name":"jak"},{"salary":45000,"name":"abc"}]');
```

I want to display only a json element which is having highest salary for example as shown below in expected result.

**Expected Result**:

```
id    jdata
-------------------------------------
1     [{"salary":45000,"name":"abc"}]
```

**My try**:

```
select t.id,each_section
from tbl_jdata t
cross join unnest(t.jdata) each_section
where t.id = 1 and (each_section ->> 'salary') in 
(
 select max(each_section ->> 'salary')
 from tbl_jdata t
 cross join unnest(t.jdata) each_section
);
```

Getting an error:

```
ERROR: function unnest(json) does not exist
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry my bad, the actually datatype is `json` for `jdata` column and data has been stored in the given format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `json_array_elements()` rater than `unnest()` on a JSON array. You can use a lateral join to get the highest element after doing that:

```
select t.id, i.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     select x.item
     from json_array_elements(t.jdata) as x(item)
     order by (x.item ->> 'salary')::int desc
     limit 1
   ) i
```

---

Note that the use of `jsonb` is recommended over `json`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jsonb, here i am going to send you a references.

https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/